# Calling a constructor from a constructor of different class

Tags: c++, object-oriented-analysis

I have a class i create a constructor for it "A". Then i create another class with a constructor "B". How do I call constructor "B" from constructor of a different class i.e "A" using c++ language?

Comment: `A::A() { B(); }` Technically, this does exactly what you are asking for, though I have a strong feeling this is not really what you are trying to do (the problem as stated makes little sense).

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what are you trying to achieve. Are you trying to instantiate B in the constructor of A? Do you have a member field of type B in the class A? Constructor is invoked upon class instance (object) creation. Where is your instance?

Answer (score 2):

If `A` inherits from `B` then you can call the base class constructor from a constructor of `A`. In C++11 you have more flexibility with this and you can use delegating constructors. Otherwise, this question doesn't make much sense.

A constructor is a special kind of function which is only called when you are creating a new object. You can't call it except when you are doing that, and usually you call a constructor when you want to make a new object -- calling the constructor is not your goal, getting the new object is.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ members or fields of a class which are object variables themselves, their constructor automatically get's called by the compiler, right when the class get's instantiated that is when it's own constructor has been called. The order of instantiating objects in C++ is like this, base class constructor get's called first, then member variables, then the most derived class which is your class.

Answer (score 1):

This will serve your purpose.

```
 class A {
  public:
     A(){
 //your code
       }
};



class B{
public :
 B():A(){
//your code
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

if both the classes are not in parent child relationship, then you may compose class A into B. below is an example.

```
class B{

public:
    B(){
        cout<<"Class B constructor"<<endl;
    }
};

class A{
    B pbj;
public:
    A(){
        cout<<"Class A Constructor"<<endl;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    A obj1;

    return 0;
}
```